# Magento extension installation issue

Tags: magento

I have my production site say **www.example.com** and development version **dev.example.com**.
I created development version by copying the production files and database.

Now when i try to install an extension from Magento Connect from the development version backend, it installs the extension in production site instead of dev one.

Any suggestion on what went wrong here?

thanks,
Balan

Comment: what version of Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete `downloader/connect.cfg` and save your settings in Magento connect: it will recreate a new file with the proper configuration.
I have no 1.4.0.1 installed here, so I can't test it, but maybe is the dist_config.xml, or config.ini: open them and see what they contains. You're looking for a path that matches your production site.